# How to prevent git branch from further commits / merging.. etc

Tags: git, gitblit

We are developing using `git` and `gitblit`. When we have finished developing on some branch, it can be that still developer accidently commit on that branch which shouldn't be the case.

How to prevent the branch from further committing and merging hotfixes into it? Can permissions be changed on the branch somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Gitblit (as of 1.8.0) does not directly support discrete branch permissions.  You can either write a Groovy hook ([example](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/blob/master/src/main/distrib/data/groovy/blockpush.groovy)) or a custom plugin ([example](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit-tbacl-plugin)) to accomplish this.